# My app get crashes because of Null pointer exception for firebaseAuth.getUid()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase. My app gets crashes whenever I click on Sign up button. I just tried to create new user authentication and a email verification for that user and finally uploading the user data to firebase. Successfully I get authentication and email verification, but not uploading my data..  I checked logcat, it shows I get error in uploading details.. **firebaseAuth.getUid()** returns null present in sendUserData() function..what to do if it returns null or how to stop returning null. Help me to update this data to firebase. I dont know how to solve.. please help me out.. Check out the last function sendUserData()

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name,password,email,age;
    private Button sign_up;
    private TextView login;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageView profilePic;
    public String Username,UserPass,UserAge,UserEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        setUp();


        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Signing up");
                progressDialog.show();
                if(validate()){


                    String user_email=email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_name=name.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password=password.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                              progressDialog.dismiss();
                                sendEmail();
                                firebaseAuth.signOut();

                            }
                            else{
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
    private void setUp(){
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        email =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        sign_up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btSignUp);
        login=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        profilePic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
    }
    private Boolean validate(){
        Boolean result=false;

        Username=name.getText().toString();
        UserPass=password.getText().toString();
        UserEmail=email.getText().toString();
        UserAge=age.getText().toString();

        if(Username.isEmpty() || UserPass.isEmpty() || UserEmail.isEmpty() || UserAge.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter all details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{

            result=true;
        }
        return result;

    }

    private void sendEmail(){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser!=null){
            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        sendUserData();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Email sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        firebaseAuth.signOut();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Email not sent, Try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

private void sendUserData(){
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
            UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(UserAge, UserEmail, Username);
            databaseReference.setValue(userProfile);
    }
}
```

I created a class UserProfile and passed these 3 parameter to the constructor which I created in UserProfile class..And I also tried it with if condition matching firebaseAuth.getUid()==null and else part with Toast message.. It always prints toast message, not uploading my data to firebase.. I'm new to this...So please post what I need to with explanation..Hope you get my question.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `firebaseAuth.signOut()` before `sendEmail()` has a chance to fully complete.  In other words, the UID is null because you signed out the user before calling `firebaseAuth.getUid()`.  You probably don't want to sign them out at all automatically - that typically only happens when the user chooses to do so.